# Deshabilitar botón de etiqueta <a> , html

Tags: html

Buen día, estoy buscando la forma de deshabilitar un botón dentro de una etiqueta `<a>`, Dejo código. Busco que el boton no se pueda presionar.

```
   <div class="player-section p16-y fxb fxb-wrp fxb-btw fxb-m">
      <div class="player-btn group"> 
<a href="https://web.com/1" class="player-btn">Anterior</a> 
<a href="https://web.com/2" class="player-btn">Siguiente 28-08-2020</a> #boton que busco desactivar
</div>
```

Intente con `disable`, `disable = True` pero no funciona

Comment: La forma correcta para deshabilitar es `disabled`, pero ¿Que es lo que quieres conseguir? además de lo obvio que es deshabilitar el `<a>`. Saludos.

Comment: @JosueArriola Gracias por responder, Busco que el boton no se pueda presionar

Comment: Entiendo, pero el tag `<a>` no tiene el atributo `disabled`, lo que puedes intentar es usar JS o jQuery para editar el `href` y poner algo como `#` o para quitar el tag `<a>`. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, te deje las opciones disponibles aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383809/46896 puedes escoger la que mejor te parezca.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes agregar una clase en el CSS que desactive los eventos del ratón:

Documentación sobre pointer-events:   [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events](http://%20developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```css
.not-active { 
            pointer-events: none; 
            cursor: default; 
        }
```

```html
    <div class="player-section p16-y fxb fxb-wrp fxb-btw fxb-m">
          <div class="player-btn group"> 
    <a href="https://web.com/1" class="player-btn">Anterior</a> 
    <a href="https://web.com/2" class="player-btn not-active">Siguiente 28-08-2020</a> #boton que busco desactivar
    </div>
```

Comment: Edité tu respuesta para que el código se pueda probar aquí mismo, utilizando _snippets_, que soportan HTML, css y javascript, pulsa el botón de editar para aprender como se hace. Un saludo.

Comment: Claro que si : )

Answer (score 3):

## Hay varias formas de hacerlo.

Partiendo de un link como este:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

### Opción #1 CSS

si le pones una clase a la etiqueta y el css siguiente, como por ejemplo:

```css
.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
    <a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

### Opción #2 jquery + css

Usando Jquery para agregar el CSS:

```js
//dentro del document ready
$.each($('a.disabled'), function(index, value) {
  $(this).css('pointer-events','none');
  $(this).css('cursor','not-allowed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

### Opción #3 jquery + Control de Evento

Usando Jquery para Controlar el Evento:

```js
//dentro del document ready
$.each($('a.disabled'), function(index, value) {
  $(this).bind('click', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a class="disabled" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: Gracias Justo lo que buscaba me funciono la opción :  Opción #2 jquery + css.

Answer (score 0):

Las etiquetas `<a>` no tienen disable. Lo único que puedes hacer para asegurarte de que esté desactivada es eliminar su href. Hay varias maneras de hacerlo:

```
<a href="https://web.com/2" class="player-btn disable-me">Siguiente 28-08-2020</a>
//jQuery
$('.disable-me').attr('href', '');
//Javascript
document.getElementsByClassName("disable-me").removeAttribute("href");
//Con css --Esta última manera no es funcional en el 100% de casos/navegadores/apps
.disable-me{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery, pada deshabilitar:

```
$(".player-btn:last-child").bind('click', false);
```

Y para volver a habilitar:

```
$(".player-btn:last-child").unbind('click', false);
```

Supongo que lo quiere hacer dependiendo de algún evento. Puede agregar al mismo alguna clase te le ponga un "opacity: .5;" cuando se realize, y viceversa al habilitarlo nuevamente.

```js
$(".player-btn:last-child").bind('click', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player-section p16-y fxb fxb-wrp fxb-btw fxb-m">
      <div class="player-btn group"> 
<a href="https://web.com/1" class="player-btn">Anterior</a> 
<a href="https://web.com/2" class="player-btn">Siguiente 28-08-2020</a> #boton que busco desactivar
</div>
```

Puedes elegir hacerlo solo con css, pero entra el inconveniende de que es muy fácil deshabilitarlo con click derecho > "inspeccionar elemento" desde el navegador.